# Multi radiobutton Click Event

Tags: c#, events, radio-button

anyone knows why this code not working?

what the code should do is get all the users in the list and make radiobutton for them and then with each click it will take the text inside the List in each user class and add them into textbox

but the thing is it only works for the last added radiobutton not all of them idk why.

```
 private void UserMessages()
    {
        int y = 8;
        int x = 7;
        
        if (TheClients.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (HandleClients C1 in TheClients)
            {
                RB = new RadioButton();
                RB.Text = C1.ClientUser;
                RB.Location = new Point(x, y);
                RB.Font = PL_UsersCont.Font;
                RB.Visible = true;
                RB.AutoSize = true;
                RB.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                RB.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
                PL_UsersCont.Controls.Add(RB);
                y += RB.Height;
            }
            RB.Click += RB_Click;
        }

    }

private void RB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (HandleClients MSGS in TheClients)
        {
            if (RB.Text == MSGS.ClientUser)
            {
                TXB_MSGS.Text = string.Empty;
                foreach (string M in MSGS.ClientMessages)
                {
                    TXB_MSGS.Text += M + "\r\n";
                }
            }
        }   
    }
```

Comment: Move the line `RB.Click += RB_Click;` to be inside the `foreach` loop

Comment: Why did you delete this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70526268/trying-to-make-a-timer-for-each-room-c-sharp

Comment: idk I just thought you didn't know what I mean, and I'm thinking of a way to do it on my own but no luck yet

Answer (score 0):

I can see two problems in the code. The first is with assigning a handler to the `Click` event. To fix this you need to move the line

```
RB.Click += RB_Click;
```

to be inside the `foreach` loop. As it stands, your code is only adding the event handler for the last created `RadioButton` and not for each one that you create.

The second, you will also find a problem in the `RB_Click` Event Handler. To ensure the RadioButton that is selected is updated, add this line of code to the `foreach` loop:

```
RB.Tag = C1;
```

And then change the `RB_Click` handler to be:

```
private void RB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RadioButton thisRadioButton = sender as RadioButton;

    if (thisRadioButton != null)
    {
        HandleClients MSGS = thisRadioButton.Tag as HandleClients;
        TXB_MSGS.Text = string.Empty;

        TXB_MSGS.Text += String.Join (Environment.NewLine, MSGS.ClientMessages);
    }   
}
```

This code will now only work on the `RadioButton` that was clicked.

Comment: It's a pleasure to help @MohamedHany. If the answer works for you, please don't forget to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to do this is to avoid the `RB_Click` method altogether.

Try this:

```
private void UserMessages()
{
    int y = 8;
    int x = 7;

    if (TheClients.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (HandleClients C1 in TheClients)
        {
            var rb = new RadioButton()
            {
                Text = C1.ClientUser,
                Location = new Point(x, y),
                Font = PL_UsersCont.Font,
                Visible = true,
                AutoSize = true,
                ForeColor = Color.Black,
                FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat,
            }
            rb.Click += (s, ea) => TXB_MSGS.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, C1.ClientMessages);
            PL_UsersCont.Controls.Add(rb)
            y += rb.Height;
        }
    }
}
```